# Jacoco aggregate report is generating Exec file instead of XML

Tags: java, maven, jacoco-maven-plugin

We have a multi-module maven project. We are using java8.

```
-Parent
-- Child 1
-- Child 2
-- Coverage-Report
```

All projects have unit test cases, those all are working good and have more than 85% of coverage. Parent pom.xml file has jacoco-profile and jacoco-maven-plugin plugin  as below

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <destFile>${sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths}</destFile>
                <append>true</append>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

In Coverage-Report module, there is only pom.xml which is for aggregating report. It has profile as jacoco as below

```
    <profile>
        <id>jacoco</id>
        <activation/>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>report-aggregate</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report-aggregate</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

To generate the report, we are using below command

```
mvn clean verify -Pjacoco
```

We do see the file getting generated which is mentioned in parent pom.xml

```
<sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>${maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory}/ocapi-promotion-service-coverage-report/target/site/jacoco-aggregate/jacoco.xml</sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>
```

However this file, jacoco.xml, is not proper XML. It has some encoded character as below. (few lines from that file)

```
��ca6191af5ae0-1a24a201}-�Sy}-ƌ|pW�\����;org/springframework/context/annotation/BeanAnnotationHelper�w~�j�zI�ZMorg/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/FilteringSpringBootCondition������e֢+org/sp
```

On jenkins we see below error

```
Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
```

I have followed an article from sonar source community https://community.sonarsource.com/t/coverage-test-data-importing-jacoco-coverage-report-in-xml-format/12151 which gives some steps. But I am not able to generate XML file. Please help.

Comment: Hello @Vikrant Korde, 

I am facing the exact same issue, were you able to fix this issue? 

Thanks, Oualid.

Comment: I had same issue, and [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-jacoco-multi-module-project) saved me.

Answer (score 1):

I finally succeed with help of [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-jacoco-multi-module-project), thanks to them!
It was mainly configuration part where I struggled.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.11</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report-aggregate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <dataFileIncludes>
                    <dataFileInclude>**/jacoco.exec</dataFileInclude>
                </dataFileIncludes>
                <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-aggregate/</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

> For a maven multi-modules project, change

`outputDirectory` = `${maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory}/target/site/jacoco-aggregate/`

Answer (score 0):

The `<destFile>` parameter you are setting in the parent is not the report XML file, it is [the agent's execution file](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html#destFile), it's always a binary file.

To make it do what you want:

1. Remove the `<destFile>` configuration.
2. Ensure your report module's pom has other modules as dependencies.
3. Run `mvn clean verify -Pjacoco`

Then `<report-module-dir>/target/site/jacoco-aggregate/jacoco.xml` will contain your aggregated XML report.